# Javascript: How can I swap elements of an array of objects (by reference, not index)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pass-by-reference, swap

I have an array of objects `a=[ {v:0}, {v:1}, {v:2}, {v:3} ] ;`

I do not have the **index** into the array, but I do have **references to** the 2 values I want to swap

```
s1=a[2] ; s2 = a[3] ;
```

How do I use these references to swap the elements of the actual array?

```
[s1,s2] = [s2,s1] ; // only swaps s1 and s2, NOT elements of the array

// a is unchanged
```

Comment: Look up the indexes of those objects in the array and then swap them by index.

Comment: You can't swap the elements of the array without looking up the indices. All that does is swap the references for `s1` and `s2`. The references for `a[2]` and `a[3]` will still reference `{v:2}` and `{v:3}` respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the reference you can safely retrieve the index by `Array.indexOf()`:

```
a.indexOf(myReference) // returns the index of the reference or -1
```

Then, with retrieved index, you can proceed as usual.

Like this:

```js
let a = [{ v: 0 }, { v: 1 }, { v: 2 }, { v: 3 }];

const s1 = a[2];
const s2 = a[3];
console.log(a.indexOf(s1))
```

Comment: I had to see that to believe it :)

Comment: @mplungjan :) it in fact works ONLY with references, if you compare two identical object in 2 different instance it will not match

Comment: Thanks!  Perhaps this should be a second question?  What if the references are actually to two different arrays (and I don't know which arrays)?  Any hope in that case?  My concept of these references as pointers is breaking down.  Much appreciated ...

Comment: What confuses me is that using the reference alone, I AM able to change the individual properties in the array without any indexOf, as in s1.v='new value' (which DOES change the array element), but I cannot change/replace the whole object referred to by s1.

Comment: But I can change their properties one by one, as in s1.v='new', which WILL change the array element's value.  right?

Answer (score 4):

There is no "pass by reference" in JavaScript. In most cases, the objects act as pointers, not references anyway.

That unfortunately means you will need to find the indexes of the objects and then swap them using those indexes:

```
// swap here, assumes the objects are really in the array
const s2index = a.indexOf(s2);
a[a.indexOf(s1)] = s2;
a[s2index] = s1;
```

Depending on your use case, you should check if the objects indeed are in the array.

Comment: You should also check if the objects are referenced by multiple indices.

Comment: does this swap `s1` and `s2` as well (along with the array elements)?

Comment: @briosheje No, the `s1` and `s2` still refer to the same object. That's why we don't need to usual `tmp` for one of the objects, but we do need a tmp variable for one of the indices.

Comment: @TomášZato I might be wrong, but as I understood the OP wants to swap both references and elements in the array, but I might be wrong. In any case, this should be the accepted answer, not sure who is downvoting all the answers, but that one should be the accepted one since it actually explains how to swap the two elements.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an utility function:

```js
function swap(list, a, b) {
  var copy = list.slice();

  copy[list.indexOf(a)] = b;
  copy[list.indexOf(b)] = a;
  
  return copy;
}

// usage
var a =[ {v:0}, {v:1}, {v:2}, {v:3} ] ;

var result = swap(a, a[1], a[3]);

console.log(result); 
// [ {v:0}, {v:3}, {v:2}, {v:1} ]
```

Keep in mind, since you are using Objects in your array, you need the exact reference to this value. E.g. this will not work:

```
var a =[ {v:0}, {v:1}, {v:2}, {v:3} ] ;

var result = swap(a, {v:1}, {v:3});

console.log(result); 
// [ {v:0}, {v:1}, {v:2}, {v:3} ]
```

Here's an alternative version which checks for all values in an Array:

```
function swap(list, a, b) {
  return list.map(function(item) {
    if (item === a) {
      return b;
    } else if (item === b) {
      return a;
    }

    return item;
  });
}
```

Comment: If `a` were to contain a particular reference at multiple indices, this would only swap the reference at the first index found.

Comment: Also true, but I'd prefer to go for the Immutable way

Answer (score -1):

Here is a one liner, just in case:

```
a.splice(a.indexOf(s2), 1, a.splice(a.indexOf(s1),1,s2)[0]);
```

Comment: Note that this has the advantage of not needing to copy anything