# Javascript: How can I replace an element of an array of objects (by reference, not index)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pointers, properties, reference

I have several arrays of objects

`a=[ {v:10}, {v:11}, {v:12}, {v:13} ]`

`b=[ {v:20}, {v:21}, {v:22}, {v:23} ]`  (etc)

and a list of references to the objects I want to replace.

I do not have **index** into the array, but I do have **references to** the items I want to replace

A reference such as this:  `s1=a[2]` or `s1=b[0]`

How do I use this reference to replace the element of the actual array without knowing which array it references?

This does not work: `s1 = {v:'new'}` , as it only replaces s1, NOT the element of the array

This is not useful `s1.v='new'` , as in reality, my objects are complex, with lots of properties, and I don't want to update them property-by-property.

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly the same [as before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57311672/javascript-how-can-i-swap-elements-of-an-array-of-objects-by-reference-not-in) - lookup the index of the item then replace by that index.

Comment: Do you mean replace them within a specific array (easy enough to do), or in any array they happen to be in, without going through a list of arrays? (Not possible AFAIK.)

Comment: @kshetline: yeah, the latter I fear.

Comment: You can, however, update the *contents* of these objects, and that update of the contents will automatically appear everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If your objects are just plain `Object`s (or at least all of the same plain-ish type), you *can* delete all properties and swap in new ones:

```
const replaceProperties = (dest, src) => {
    Object.keys(dest).forEach(key => {
        delete dest[key];
    });

    Object.assign(dest, src);
};

replaceProperties(s1, {v: 'new'});
```

This isn’t a good idea for a few reasons, though, so see if you can start having indexes into the array.

If your objects are all the same *shape* as well (i.e. always have the same properties), taking advantage of that is much better, and is the multi-property equivalent of repeated `s1.v = 'new'`s:

```
Object.assign(s1, {v: 'new'});
```